# In android How to use a variable(without making it final) from outer class in onAnimationEnd() method in AnimatorListener

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am trying to change the image of an ImageButton when the translate animation of another ImageView has ended. I have an AnimatorListener for the animation and would like to pass the ImageButton value in the onAnimationEnd method so that I know which ImageButton to change(some computation take place in the code to decide which Imagebutton to change). My code is as follows. Please help me!!!

```
//animation of an imageview
ObjectAnimator move =ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myAnimation1,"translationX",20);

//calculating which image to change to for the ImageButton
int id2 = this.getResources().getIdentifier("r" + a[m], "drawable", this.getBaseContext().getPackageName());

//adding animtor listener

move.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(ImageButton,id2) {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        ImageButton.setImageResource(id2); //Not able to use ImageButton and id2...says it has to be final but I don't want it to be final

                        ImageButton.setClickable(true);

                    }});
```

Comment: what's wrong with final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create another final variable?

```
int id2 = this.getResources().getIdentifier("r" + a[m], "drawable", this.getBaseContext().getPackageName());

final int idFinal = id2;

//adding animtor listener

move.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(ImageButton,id2) {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        ImageButton.setImageResource(idFinal); //Not able to use ImageButton and id2...says it has to be final but I don't want it to be final

                        ImageButton.setClickable(true);

                    }});
```

Comment: But just wanted to know if it is possible to pass values to the AnimationListener onAnimationEnd method.

Comment: Not from the default implementation of the AnimatorListener, you could try implementing your own AnimatorListener to do that but I dont know if it would be worth the effort.